# Get function declaration from function call expression eclipse cdt

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Assume that I am able to visit all function call expression in c file, what I need to get the function definition node for that function call, the function definition may be in another C file, I tried the code below

```
@Override
protected int visit(IASTFunctionCallExpression functionCall) {

    IASTExpression functionNameExp = functionCallExp.getFunctionNameExpression();
        IASTName fn = ((IASTIdExpression) functionNameExp).getName() ;
        IBinding binding = fn.resolveBinding(); //binding is retrieved successfully 
        IName[] defs = ast.getDefinitions(binding);
        for(IName def : definitions) {
             //I want to get the function definition node in the other file
        }
}
```

but when I try to evaluate the "defs" in the debug mode an error says that is fired

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I was able to came over this exception by re-build the project index.

The problem happened in mehtod CIndex#findNames in the function return:
return result.toArray(new IIndexName[result.size()]);
while the result size to be zero, it will through that exception, I notice that this style of return used heavily in the CIndex class

[HighCommander4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141719/highcommander4)

Comment: now I don't know how to get the function definition in the other file by definition name, that came out of ast.getDefinitions

Comment: I have no idea about the `DebugException`, but if the functions are defined in a different file, you want to `findDefinitions()` on the `IIndex`, not the AST.